# How to get the changed input box value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having jquery as follows,

```
$(document).on('click', '.save_button', function (e) { 
    var amount = $('.actual_pay').val();
});
```

Which means when a user clicks the button with class `save_button`, the script executes and sets the value of the var `amount` to the value of the field with class `actual_pay`.

Up to this no problems and it is working fine, but the input box with class name `actual_pay` is editable and any time the value can be changed, I have to detect the changed value of the input box, for which i have tried with

```
var amount = $('.actual_pay').val().change();
```

But it is showing error:

> .change is not a function.

How to detect the change happening to the class `actual_pay` and to store the changed value to the amount variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach an `input`  event listener.

```js
var amount;
$('.actual_pay').on("input", function(){
  console.log("Something is changed in actual_pay");
  amount = $(this).val(); // save val
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="actual_pay">
```

Actions which invoke input events are

- Entering some text into an element.
- Cutting, deleting or pasting some content.
- Dropping some content into an element. (only in Google Chrome and Safari)

Comment: Is there any option to change this along with ```$('.actual_pay').val();```, without giving a seperate function ?

Comment: @ManiRaj sorry I dont understand your question. Could you explain?

Comment: I mean i need to set this to a variable, how can i do it with your answer?
The variable should have the changed value..

Comment: Change console.log to  `amount = $(this).val();` assuming amount is a global var

Comment: @ManiRaj you want to set what to a variable? And where?

Comment: @mplungjan maybe that might help/

Comment: @void - I think he meant what I added to your function

Comment: Variable amount should get the changed value of the input box with class ```actual_pay```.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.actual_pay').val().change();` won't work because this is wrong approach. You can do by following method

```
$('.actual_pay').on('input',function(){
 alert('Something Modified');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get value of that input box with this function:

```
$( "input.actual_pay" ).keyup(function() {

        var amount = $(this).val();
    });
```

If you are changing that input manually, you will use 'keyup', otherwise you should use

```
$( "input.actual_pay" ).change(function() {

        var amount = $(this).val();
    });
```